# Flask App not getting Debugged using VS Code

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, visual-studio-code, wsgi

I have successfully running application using Flask in python

which has one web page in HTML & 4 API's. i wanted to debug using breakpoints.

whenever i try to debug using VS code. it throws me below error.

```
jatingarg$  cd /Users/jatingarg/Desktop/infosys/pythonPractice/samplePython ; /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python /Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 50004 -- -m flask run --no-debugger --no-reload 
E+00000.018: Error determining module path for sys.argv
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "/Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 307, in run_module
                 _, _, _, argv_0 = runpy._get_module_details(target_as_str)
               File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 107, in _get_module_details
                 raise error(format(e))
             ImportError: No module named flask
             
             Stack where logged:
               File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
                 "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
               File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
                 exec code in run_globals
               File "/Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
                 cli.main()
               File "/Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444, in main
                 run()
               File "/Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 309, in run_module
                 log.swallow_exception("Error determining module path for sys.argv")
               File "/Users/jatingarg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/common/log.py", line 218, in swallow_exception
                 _exception(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
             

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named flask
```

My Launch.JSON

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My App Config

```
class AppConfig(BaseConfig):
    # defaults can be specified, and properties can be optional
    DEBUG = ConfigProperty(property_type=BooleanType(), required=False, default=True)

app_config = AppConfig([EnvLoader()])
```

It has WSGI integrated, it runs well.

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment before running `flask run`?

Comment: Yes i tried that.. activating venv .. flask run.. then api stops working..

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the python version in VS code

[image]